# Setting up Eclipse to use Lettuce

Tags: python, eclipse, bdd, functional-testing, lettuce

I am starting off with Lettuce to test a web application. The problem is I am unaware of how to configure Eclipse so that it runs my steps file. The web also seems pretty unaware of this and this is hence my last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an automated solution you can look at the Eclipse `External Tools` capability. This is documented in the [Eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp) for the workbench. Follow the links `Workbench User Guide ==> Concepts ==> Ant & External Tools ==> External Tools` .

for interactive use, you can run `lettuce` from the Python console within Eclipse if you have `Pydev` installed, and you should if you use Eclipse for Python development.